# Symfony 3: How to cleanup cache directory?

Tags: caching, symfony

Is there some kind of automatic cleanup or garbage collector that cleans cache/ directory?

I deployed my project on the production server, but each day I see that the cache/ directory grows and soon I will hit the limit of the shared hosting for allowed inods count.

For example I have 5000+ files or directories in bin/cache/prod/pools and they grow each day.

Comment: So what sort of stuff is in pools?  I don't have that directory on my production stuff.  I could understand things like var/sessions growing but my production cache stays constant.

Answer (score 1):

That's the idea of using cache,  to create files instead  using CPU.
Add it's normal :/  . The only good anwser is to change  hosting provider.

Of course you can try add php app/console cache:clear -e prod  to cron , or you can try to move cache to memory (some memcache/redis based solution ), but the best anwser is - change hosting provider( or talk with them about that limit)

Comment: This is not a solution. I can always switch to higher plan with more allowed inodes, but I think that the cache should be cleaned somehow.
If I do nothing how big it will become after months? 1 000 000 files? 10 000 000 files?

Comment: AFAIK there is no garbage collector in symfony cache, but AFAIR cache ovewrites it's own files , so it  shouldn't grow  to inifinite size :)